# WPF - Bind combobox to List of custom class objects

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF project with a combobox that I'm trying to bind to a List of `ComboboxItem` objects.  `ComboboxItem` is a class that I created for my sample project.  This is partially working...  I have my three items available to the combobox, but the displayed value is blank and the value of `combobox.SelectedValue` is null.  I've seen several stackoverflow posts and other blog posts about how to do this.  And as far as I can tell, I'm doing this right.  But obviously I'm doing something wrong.  Here is the source code for a test project...

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApp_ComboBoxes.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cboMyCombo" Grid.Row="0" 
                  SelectionChanged="cboMyCombo_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C# Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<ComboboxItem> _list = new List<ComboboxItem>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        _list.Add(new ComboboxItem() { DisplayValue = "One", InternalValue = "1" });
        _list.Add(new ComboboxItem() { DisplayValue = "Two", InternalValue = "2" });
        _list.Add(new ComboboxItem() { DisplayValue = "Three", InternalValue = "3" });

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void cboMyCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Selected Item: {0}, Selected Value: {1}", cb.SelectedItem, cb.SelectedValue));
        }
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cboMyCombo.ItemsSource = _list;
        cboMyCombo.DisplayMemberPath = "DisplayValue";
        cboMyCombo.SelectedValuePath = "InternalValue";
    }
}
```

ComboboxItem Class:

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string DisplayValue;
    public string InternalValue;
}
```

Comment: Create properties for DisplayValue and InternalValue instead of having them as public members

Comment: Why do you do your databinding in your code behind, when you can do it much cleaner [in your xaml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: This is just a test project.  I tried many iterations of using XAML and code-behind while trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.  Turns out it was the ComboboxItem class all along.  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string DisplayValue;
    public string InternalValue;
}
```

to

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string DisplayValue {get;set;}
    public string InternalValue {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Wow.  I guess I was so focused on the combobox I missed an obvious issue.  *sigh*  thank you.  (This was a case of "couldn't see the forest for the trees".)  I remember reading, now that you have to have a `Property` to bind to.  In hindsight, this is obvious.